# Facebook js sdk "/me/permissions" returning no access token (js sdk / php sdk conflict?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

The below console logs "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." Apparently my js isn't getting the access token from php - how do I rectify this?The code below is a virtual clone of what FB posted on their blog:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

```
<?php
$basePath = "/usr/lib/fb";

// Include the fb sdk
require 'fb/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '#####', // I do repeat this in fb.js so I can externalize it
  'secret' => '#####',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user_profile) { ?>
      Your user profile is 
      <pre>            
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre> 
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>               
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>', 
          cookie: true, 
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });

        FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        } );

      };


      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loaded and initiated the fb sdk, but you need to authenticate the user.
For js authentication alone you need to use the [FB.login method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), but if your php is in charge of authenticating the user then you can just call [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/), like:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>', 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response1) {
        if (response1.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response2) {
                console.log(response2);
            });
        }
        else {
            // user is not logged in or not authorized with the app.
            // use a login button or FB.login
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `me/permissions` even when user hasnt authorised your app,

Do this instead,

```
<?php if ($user_profile): ?>
   FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
      console.log(response);
   });
<?php endif; ?>
```